# Getting the count of most repeated records in Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am working on an application in which I have to store play history of a song in the data table. I have a table named PlayHistory which has four columns.

```
Id | SoundRecordingId(FK) | UserId(FK) | DateTime
```

Now i have to implement a query that will return the songs that are in trending phase i.e. being mostly played. I have written the following query in sql server that returns me data somehow closer to what I want.

```
select  COUNT(*) as High,SoundRecordingId
from PlayHistory
where DateTime >= GETDATE()-30
group by  SoundRecordingId
Having COUNT(*) > 1
order by SoundRecordingId desc
```

It returned me following data:

```
High  SoundRecordingId
2       5
2       3
```

Which means Song with Ids 5 and 3 were played the most number of times i.e.2
How can I implement this through Linq in c#.
I have done this so far:

```
        DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
        var monthBefore = d.AddMonths(-1);
        var list =
            _db.PlayHistories
            .OrderByDescending(x=>x.SoundRecordingId)
            .Where(t => t.DateTime >= monthBefore)
            .GroupBy(x=>x.SoundRecordingId)
            .Take(20)
            .ToList();
```

It returns me list of whole table with the count of SoundRecording objects but i want just count of the most repeated records.
Thanks

Comment: `.OrderByDescending(x=>x.SoundRecordingId)...` allready *is* linq. So what else do you want?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I have edited my question

Comment: Your issue is that your linq does not perform a count, there is an overload to `GroupBy` which allows you to do this. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an overload of the `.GroupBy` method which will solve your problem.

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
    var monthBefore = d.AddMonths(-1);
    var list =
        _db.PlayHistories
        .OrderByDescending(x=>x.SoundRecordingId)
        .Where(t => t.DateTime >= monthBefore)

        .GroupBy(x=>x.SoundRecordingId, (key,values) => new {SoundRecordingID=key, High=values.count()})

        .Take(20)
        .ToList();
```

I have simply added the result selector to the `GroupBy` method call here which does the same transformation you have written in your SQL.

The method overload in question is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549393(v=vs.110).aspx)

To go further into your problem, you will probably want to do another `OrderByDescending` to get your results in popularity order. To match the SQL statement you also have to filter for only counts > 1.

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
    var monthBefore = d.AddMonths(-1);
    var list =
        _db.PlayHistories
        .Where(t => t.DateTime >= monthBefore)
        .GroupBy(x=>x.SoundRecordingId, (key,values) => new {SoundRecordingID=key, High=values.count()})
        .Where(x=>x.High>1)
        .OrderByDescending(x=>x.High)
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

I like the 'linq' syntax it's similar to SQL

```
var query = from history in _db.PlayHistories
            where history.DateTime >= monthBefore
            group history by history.SoundRecordingId into historyGroup
            where historyGroup.Count() > 1
            orderby historyGroup.Key
            select new { High = historyGroup.Count(), SoundRecordingId = historyGroup.Key };

var data = query.Take(20).ToList();
```

Comment: That´s not the "linq-syntax", it´s called the *query-syntax* , in contrast to the *method syntax*. Nevertheless this isn´t wnat OP is asking.

Comment: Thanks @Filip using your solution i was able to get the required result, but its in query synatx, i wanted to use method syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You´re allmost done. Just order your list by the count and take the first:

```
var max =
        _db.PlayHistories
        .OrderByDescending(x=>x.SoundRecordingId)
        .Where(t => t.DateTime >= monthBefore)
        .GroupBy(x=>x.SoundRecordingId)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
        .First();
```

This gives you a single key-value-pair where the `Key` is your `SoundRecordingId` and the value is the number of its occurences in your input-list.

EDIT: To get all records with that amount chose this instead:

```
var grouped =
        _db.PlayHistories
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.SoundRecordingId)
        .Where(t => t.DateTime >= monthBefore)
        .GroupBy(x => x.SoundRecordingId)
        .Select(x => new { Id = x.Key, Count = x.Count() }
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
        .ToList();
var maxCount = grouped.First().Count;
var result = grouped.Where(x => x.Count == maxCount);
```

Comment: Shouldn't be the `Take` after `OrderByDescending` and `ToList()` instead of `First()`?

Comment: This only gave me a single record. There can be more than one record, like my example.

Answer (score 0):

This solves the problem by giving you what you asked for.  Your query in LINQ, returning just the play counts.

```
var list = _db.PlayHistories.Where(x => x.DateTimeProp > (DateTime.Now).AddMonths(-1))
           .OrderByDescending(y => y.SoundRecordingId.Count())
           .ThenBy(z => z.SoundRecordingId)
           .Select(xx => xx.SoundRecordingId).Take(20).ToList();
```

Comment: The OP is asking for a simple code example.  There is no commentary needed.  Maybe I should have added "I like LINQ syntax" (no such thing) and you wouldn't have lectured me.  Or I could write about the GroupBy overloads even though this query does not need GroupBy for any reason.

Comment: Why so salty? You know what, I will just not take your little rant personal and hope it helped you relieve some stress..

Comment: Not every question needs code and not every answer benefits from a caption. "How do I type this single query in a different syntax" is a good example. Read the thread first before calling someone out please.

Comment: you are right, it was not **necessary** to provide context for your answer and the comment was probably a little much. I still think that almost every answer (including yours) could benefit frome some short explaination as to what you are doing, as most people asking questions are newcomers or struggeling with a certain topic and most solutions can benefit from some guidance